# connection error while connecting mongodb using python

Tags: python-3.x, connection, pymongo

**PYTHON CODE**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == "__main__":

     client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
```

..I even tried

```
client = MongoClient()
```

getting this error..

**pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

I am using Windows 10, the version of pymongo is 3.0.3 and I am using python 3.5

Comment: can you confirm you have a mongod process running on your local port 27017?

Comment: how can i confirm it ?

Comment: Typically you would have run the mongod command in command line. MongoClient needs to connect to a mongodb server.